# System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field:

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, soql

I have a custom object called `Technology__c` and join object called `AccountTechnologies` which is a join object between Account and Technology__c .So AccountTechnologies has a master detail relationship from both sides.
I have added a `count__c` roll-up summary field in the `Technology__c` to get the count But when i access it in the visual force page I get the following error

```
      System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Technology__c.count__c
```

The following is the visualforce page code

```
      <apex:pageBlockTable title="Technologies" value="{!AllTechnologies}"
                var="t">
                <apex:column value="{!t.Name}" headerValue="Technologies" />
                <apex:column value="{!t.count__c}" headerValue="Count" width="20%">

                </apex:column>        
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Are you using the standard controller for the Visualforce page or a custom controller (or extension)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add the `Count__c` field to your query in your custom controller.

-- Edit --

If you're querying off of Technologies, the query would look like this:
`[Select Id, Name, Count__c From Technology__c];`

If you're querying off of a junction object, you would need to query the relationship using a subquery. You can check the Technology or AccountTechnologies object definition (App Setup > Create > Objects) and click the Master-Detail field to find the Child Relationship Name. Add an `__r` to that relationship name to find what object to subquery from.

To get the `Technology__r` values into another object you would use the `getSObjects()` method on the Account. This [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_dynamic_dml.htm) has a great example at the bottom.

Also, check the [custom controller documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_controller_custom.htm) for more information.

Comment: but it is column and the Technology keeps changing. how to pass that to a customcontroller so that it can be seen in VF

Comment: The var t needs to passed to the  method in the controller and then be returned to VF to display the count. i dont know how to pass the param t to the controller and process it so that the value is shown in the column

Comment: how do i pass var t to the controller ..sorry i am a newbie in salesforce

Comment: I edited the answer above adding a description of how to sub-query for the Technology object from Account. Between the Custom Controller documentation and the dynamic SOQL documentation, you should be all set.

Comment: Var `t` is set by the `<apex:pageblocktable>` it doesn't need to be passed. It's a single instance of (or one record from) `Technologies`.

Comment: But the roll-up summary field `count__c` keeps the count of the children it has in the join table so y does technology__c.count__c not work

Comment: how do i access Var `t` in my controller?

Comment: Is `Count__c` on Account or Technology__c? Are you trying to count the number of Technology records? Var `t` is not accessible in the controller; you would need to look at the Technologies (or Technology__r) list.

Comment: I think I finally understand your question. I misunderstood the part about having an object between Account and Technology. Do multiple Accounts need to be related to multiple Technologies?

Comment: `count__C` in on technology__c. and AccountsTechnologiesAssociation is the join table which with columns ChildofAccount and ChildofTechnology {master detail from both side}

Comment: ya a many to many relationship which is stored in AccountsTechnologiesAssociation__c

Comment: And, in the Visualforce page you want to display all Technologies for a specific Account, or all Accounts and all Technologies?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7039/discussion-between-matthew-keefe-and-yatish-mehta)